# Cannot Remove Preinstalled Apps in 22.04

Tags: uninstall, default-programs, 22.04

One of the things I do immediately post-installation is remove about a dozen preinstalled apps.  Use Aisleriot Solitaire as the example here.

I did a new (erase disk) install of 22.04.  As usual, went into software, clicked the briefcase, selected "installed" and Aisleriot was at the top of the list, as usual.  I noted that the button title had changed from "Remove" (20.04) to "Uninstall" (22.04).  I clicked "Uninstall" and confirmed.

Got "Cannot uninstall Aisleriot.  No packages found."  Same for all other programs I want to get rid of.  Is this a bug or do I need to do something different to unclutter the installation?

"apt remove aisleriot" appeared to work, but actually had no effect.

Comment: What is the output from `dpkg -l aisleriot`

Comment: I know this isn't an answer to your question, but are the apps you normally remove still installed in the "minimal install" option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a bug in Ubuntu Software.  `sudo apt remove *` does remove the package, but it doesn't update the list in Ubuntu Software until the next time you log in.

Comment: Thanks.  Shoulda known better than to try .0 of anything.  I installed alongside 20.04.4 to get an answer to user10489's question while keeping the reinstall I did this morning, and there was your solution.

Answer (score 3):

I solved these issues on Ubuntu 22.04 related at:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/snap-store-desktop/+bug/1969303

and

https://github.com/PackageKit/PackageKit/commit/cfd297aeb51bde67269d74c5a762634314e918b6

Using these commands:

```
killall snap-store

sudo snap refresh
```